# Device not connecting to API Service

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

I'm publishing my WEB API to LocalISS, Accessing it in the built in Emulator works, but when Switching to actual Device it returns `System.OperationCanceledException:  System.Threading.CancellationToken.`

I also tried Converyor by keyoti, And it's the same. Works with emulator but not in actual device

Comment: Did you added inbound rule in firewall?

Comment: Hi , you should keep the physical device and web api on the same network segment . **eg**: API : `192.168.1.23:6399` , IP of the physical device : `192.168.1.29` .

Comment: @Junior Jiang That's the problem the API and the phone is in the same network, I also tried the published version of the Web API, still doesn't work

Comment: @motalr Okey , it's strange . Which physical device tested it , and whehter used another device to check it . By the way , you can type API in Browser of Phone to check whehter can connect it .

Comment: @Junior Jiang, i used 2 devices, I tried to access the api from the phone and i received the site can't be reached response , so i guess there's a problem with the web api, thank you

Comment: @motalr Okey , if find the reason or solution remember to share here later :-)

Comment: sure, will do =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the IP Settings in the WiFi connection to static and set my IP to the same network segment. Turns out the IP Settings is default to dynamic DHCP.